# Declare an object inside a C++ class

Tags: c++, oop, generics

I am trying to make a linked list in C++ using Generics. But when I declare a Node object inside my class I get this error `library.h:7:3: error: 'Node' does not name a type  Node<T> n;`

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList{
public:
  int length;

  Node<T> n;

  LinkedList(){

  }

};

template <typename T>
class Node{
public:
  int value;
  Node *next;
  Node(int value){
    this->value = value;
  }
};
```

Comment: You need to flip the definitions around since you can't use something you haven't declared yet.

Comment: And how can I do this?

Comment: Move the code for `LinkedList` to be after `Node`

Comment: Or even better @Nathan, stick `Node` in `LinkedList` since it's an implementation detail that no one outside of the class should know or care about.

Comment: Now I get another error, but if I declare the node as ```Node<T>* n;``` I don't get any errors. Should I let the '*' there?

Comment: `Node<T> n;` tries to create a new `Node` using the default constructor. But since you've declared a constructor that takes an `int`, no default constructor is created for you--so none exists! Creating a pointer isn't actually creating an object, so no constructor is called, which is why that works. Either specify a value when you create the `Node`, or create a pointer.